# Некорректно работает метод GET HttpStatus (Как пофиксить?)

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, response

Имею следующий код

```
try {
               URL url = new URL(params[0]);
               HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
               connection.setUseCaches(false);
               //System.out.println();
               connection.connect();
               int code = connection.getResponseCode();
               connection.disconnect();

               if (code==200) {
                   result = 1;
               }
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   result = 0;
                   //System.out.println("ERR");
               }
```

При проверке url-адреса `http://109.194.47.19:8000/echo` показывает ответ 200 ОК, хотя при переходе по адресу = не работает.

Проверяю url-потоки радиостанций таким образом. И должно показать что ссылка на поток битая, (т.к не воспроизводится поток). но показывает , что `200 ОК`. Можно ли как то исправить?

Comment: Код 400 обозначает ошибку и вместе с "OK" выглядит странно.

Comment: перепутал.. код 200.

Comment: Код 200 означает, что сервер ответил, а вот что он ответил - другой вопрос. По приведённому Вами адресу ответ: **The file you requested could not be found**

Comment: Как проверять то, рабочий поток или нет? Раз ответ 200 приходит для всего подряд?

Comment: Однозначный результат даст только попытка воспроизвести сам поток. Упал с ошибкой или моментально кончился или таймаут вышел - значит всё, кина не будет.

Comment: у меня более 700 радиостанций в списке, и получается мне нужно воспроизводить их все для проверки? я просто получаю статус ответа от сервера, и делаю условие на всякий случай, есть ли в Content-Type: содержимое [audio/***]

Comment: Ну можно и так, наверное, только проверять сам стрим. Запрос на `/echo` сервер реализовывать не обязан. И вообще-то по адресу http://109.194.47.19:8000 открывается не поток, а список станций - может от этого у Вас проблемы. Насколько я помню, подобные программы выводят весь список и помечают мёртвые адреса только после попытки их воспроизведения, либо проверка производится на собственном сервере и приложение берёт оттуда уже чистый список.

Comment: @woesss,, то что сейчас по адресу `109.194.47.19:8000` открывается не поток а список станций, мне не интересно по факту. Есть адрес, `http://109.194.47.19:8000/echo` по которому играл когда то поток. Потом перестал работать. Это просто пример. Именно к адресу `http://109.194.47.19:8000/echo` обращаюсь, ибо он в базе лежит., если он не доступен, то просто помечаю станцию, что не рабочая. Схему впринципе реализовал,  и вроде как работает.. Но не все адреса станций определяет верно. Иногда бывают адреса, которые с компьютера открываются и воспроизводится поток, а с приложения - ошибку даёт 404

Comment: что-то придумывать , и перегружать приложение лишними запросами, ради таких станций, это перебор. Проще посидеть и погуглить альтернативный поток радиостанции.